# Reinstalling .NET Framework 4.0 leads to app crash with error CLR20r3

Tags: c#, .net, dll, frameworks, oxyplot

I wrote my application in Visual Studio 2012. I use an external reference to OxyPlot library (dll). I've tested my application on some machines with Windows 7 (the same build, Framework 4.0 was installed). The application executed normally, but on a machine with Windows XP it failed (Framework 4.0 was installed too).
After that I've installed Framework 4.5 on a machine with Windows 7, then removed Framework 4.5 (from Control Panel => Programms and Features) and installed back Framework 4.0 (Standalone Installer). My application didn't run with error: `CLR20r3`.

```
Details:
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: rm.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 525fd886
  Problem Signature 04: OxyPlot
  Problem Signature 05: 2013.1.100.1
  Problem Signature 06: 525451de
  Problem Signature 07: 218
  Problem Signature 08: 0
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileLoadException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1049
```

After all I deleted OxyPlot library from my project, recompiled it and my app starts normally on each machines.
Why did reinstalling Framework 4.0 caused my application to crash, and why it didn't run on Windows XP? How should I solve this problem? What is the relation between Framework 4.0 and the external OxyPlot dll ?

Answer (score 0):

I OxyPlot does not support .Net 3.5, only 4 and up.

Windows XP doesn't support .Net 4.5, only 4 (assuming you have service pack 3).

Usually, VS2012 will install .Net4.5 libraries.

Might be some issue with that. (Installing both VS2010 & 2012 on the same Win 7 machine caused visual studio 2010 to break when using the designer). You might be facing a similar issue.

On a different note, if you're targeting windows XP, your safe bet would be to build your app targeting .Net 2 ... (darn, XP is old)...

Comment: Appication executed normally on Windows 7 with installed Framework 4.0 (on machine where Visual Studio is not installed). But after next operations:

Comment: Win 7 should be ok. I doubt win XP would be ok on all occasions. 
What where you trying to say after: "But after next operations:-" ?

Comment: Appication executed normally on Windows 7 with installed Framework 4.0 (on machine where Visual Studio is not installed). But after next operations: install framework 4.5 on framework 4.0 => uninstalling 4.5 => installing again framework 4.0 back =>> after these operations appliation crashed. So why did reinstalling 4.0 crash app?

Comment: What's your target on the VS2012 (4? 4.5?)
Also, this error happened to people who are missing the reference or the dll. A suggestion/workaround is to make sure you have the `CopyLocal=true` on your app config.
Installing 4.5 over 4 causes some funny issues as I mentioned before. Removing and reinstalling them, not always fixes it. Couldn't say much more with the information you supplied I'm afraid.

Comment: VS2012 target is 4.0. Dll's property "CopyLocal=true".

Comment: Framework 4.0 is installed on Windows XP but app crushed. And on Windows 7 with reinstalled Framework 4.0 app crushed too. I suppose there is the same matter of crushing in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. **I solved the problem after installing a specific .Net 4.0 security update**: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2604121.

My WPF application targets .Net Framework 4.0 and use OxyPlot 2014.1.277.1.

For this application, I also did some installing/unistalling testing removing each time .Net Framework 4.0 (which is a prerequisite accomplished by setup).

When I ran the application I got the following error:

Details:
Problem signature:

```
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3  
 Problem Signature 01: seling.newmonitor.gui.exe  
 Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0  
 Problem Signature 03: 5379d9c4  
 Problem Signature 04: OxyPlot.Wpf  
 Problem Signature 05: 2014.1.277.1  
 Problem Signature 06: 534623ca  
 Problem Signature 07: 224  
 Problem Signature 08: 33  
 Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileLoadException  
 OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48  
 Locale ID: 1040  
 Additional Informations 1: 0a9e  
 Additional Informations 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789  
 Additional Informations 3: 0a9e  
 Additional Informations 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I then installed KB2487367 update but nothing changed: Application was terminated showing the error above.
**After installing KB2604121 the application worked fine, and I was able to see the OxyPlot graph.**
Those updates was proposed by Windows Update.

This was the error stack I had before installing KB2604121:

Application: Seling.NewMonitor.GUI.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException Stack:

```
at OxyPlot.PlotModel.Update(Boolean)  
at OxyPlot.Wpf.Plot.UpdateModel(Boolean)  
at OxyPlot.Wpf.Plot.InvalidatePlot(Boolean)  
at OxyPlot.Wpf.Plot.PlotLoaded(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)  
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)  
...  
at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)  
at Seling.NewMonitor.GUI.App.Main()
```

Hope this helps!